# WPF Editable combobox - preserve input when updating observable list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, observablecollection

How can I get my editable combobox to both accept and preserve user input, while dynamically updating options available in the combobox?

What I'm trying to accomplish is allowing the user to begin typing a query, and have query suggestions appear based on what has been typed so far. Getting the suggestions and updating the contents of the comobobox is going well, but on every update, the input is wiped out and replaced with the first entry in the updated list.

Here's what I've tried so far ( along with other similar SO suggestions that didn't quite pan out )

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmboSearchField" Margin="197,10,0,0" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
 IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchTopics}" 
 KeyUp="GetSearchTopics"/>
```

And my code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> SearchTopics {get;set;}

void GetSearchTopics(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   bool showDropdown = this.cmboSearchField.IsDropDownOpen;

   if ((e.Key >= Key.D0) && (e.Key <= Key.Z))
   {
      query = this.cmboSearchField.Text;

      List<string> topics = GetQueryRecommendations(query);

      _searchTopics.Clear();

      _searchTopics.Add(query); //add the query back to the top

      //stuffing the list into a new ObservableCollection always
      //rendered empty when the dropdown was open          
      foreach (string topic in topics)
      {
         _searchTopics.Add(topic);
      }

      this.cmboSearchField.SelectedItem = query; //set the query as the current selected item

      //this.cmboSearchField.Text = query; //this didn't work either   

      showDropdown = true;
   }


   this.cmboSearchField.IsDropDownOpen = showDropdown;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out updating the `ObservableCollection` had nothing to do with the behavior I was seeing. I realized later that it was acting as though typing was doing a search for a matching entry in the drop down collection, thus replacing whatever input the user provided every time.

That was exactly what was happening. setting the `IsTexSearchEnabled` attribute of the `ComboBox` element to false in the window XAML solved the problem.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmboSearchField" Margin="218,10,43,0" 
 IsTextSearchEnabled="false" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchTopics}" 
 KeyUp="GetSearchTopics"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't clear the observablecollection.

If you clear the collection then at some point the list is empty and the reference to the selecteditem is lost.

Instead, just look at which items are already in there and only add the ones that are not yet available.

Comment: I'm afraid the behavior I'm still seeing disagrees. Even when I'm not clearing the collection, the SelectedItem is being overwritten; thus destroying whatever the user types in.